# Why is Android changing public bytes to 129?

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors, byte

I was forced to upgrade my apps compileSdkVersion to 25, but in doing so, every public byte variable in my app no longer has valid values (turns to 129 after setting it, no matter what).

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public byte abyte;
    public SomeClass()
    {
        abyte=-128;//bytes valid range are from -128 to 127
        System.out.println("abyte = "+abyte);//prints out 129 as the value
    }
}
```

Why is Android setting all public bytes to 129? Creating a local variable byte and setting it stays at whatever value I set it at. It works on Java on the PC, and older (19) compileSdkVersion. I use bytes a lot, since my app is multiplayer.

Comment: Your test is not showing that `abyte` is 129. It is showing that `"abyte = "+abyte` prints 129. This might occur due to changes in how a `byte` gets represented when concatenated with a `String`.

Comment: It isn't the println that's failing-  its the conversion.  YOu're calling println with a String parameter, not a byte parameter.  The string concatentation is treating the byte as an unsigned value rather than a signed value.  Probably because its treating it as a character.  Try Byte.toString(value)